# Need to add style(background color) to each cell in excel angular,xlsx "version": "0.14.1",

Tags: angular, excel, download, xlsx, worksheet-function

How to style the cell based on json response

json response:

```json
{
    "position": 0,
    "clientLocation": "XPS-Kitchen",
    "upStream": "92.772",
    "downStream": "99.829",
    "minExpUpstreamValue": "65",
    "minExpDownstreamValue": "70",
    "upsStatus": "Success",
    "dwsStatus": "Success"
},
```

I want to display client location,upstream and downstream value ,
background color of upstream and downstream depends on upsStatus and dwsStatus.
green if sucess and red if failure,

Using the below library:

```
"xlsx": {
  "version": "0.14.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/xlsx/-/xlsx-0.14.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-7hjB5YuyJo1fuuzXQjwuxD8LSUzE4Rxu5ToC3fB5JSunZxGjLcgKg69bEFG9GYoxeVDx5GL0k1dUodlvaQNRQw==",
  "requires": {
    "adler-32": "~1.2.0",
    "cfb": "^1.1.0",
    "codepage": "~1.14.0",
    "commander": "~2.17.1",
    "crc-32": "~1.2.0",
    "exit-on-epipe": "~1.0.1",
    "ssf": "~0.10.2"
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally style an HTML element like this

```
<div [style.background]="jsonObj.upsStatus == 'Success' ? 'green' : 'red'">
</div>
```

You'll need to have json object in a variable (depends on your logic)

Thanks.

Comment: i need this in excel download angular using xlsx library